# LINQ and the dynamic List Type

Tags: c#, linq, list

Have class:

```
public class SignalRounding
{
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public double round { get; set; }
}
public class SignalRoundingView
{
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public double round { get; set; }
}
```

Create list

```
public static List<SignalRounding> SignalR;
SignalR = new List<SignalRounding>();
ListView.ItemsSource = SignalR;
ListView.Items.Refresh();
```

Add some information with certain parameters

```
try
{
 var r = SignalR.Where(t => t.LastUpdated >= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10))
 .GroupBy(g => g.symbol)
 .Select(s => new SignalRoundingView()
  {
    LastUpdated = s.Max(x => x.LastUpdated),
    Quantity = s.Count(),
    symbol = s.Key,
    price = s.Single(l => l.LastUpdated == s.Max(x => x.LastUpdated)).price,
    round = s.Single(l => l.LastUpdated == s.Max(x => x.LastUpdated)).round
  })
.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdated)
.ThenByDescending(x => x.Quantity).ToList();

Filter3List.ItemsSource = r;
Filter3List.Items.Refresh();
}
catch (Exception){throw;}
```

`List<SignalRounding> SignalR` is dynamic - sometimes there is an error. 
With the following description: Collection was modified; the operation cannot be performed enumerating.

How fix it?

Comment: Use a thread safe list instead? e.g. `ConcurrentBag<T>`

Comment: I use this: `if (Filter3List.Dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread){ code} else Filter3List.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate{}));`

Comment: But you still have multiple threads accessing the list which will throw exceptions. Change `List<T>` to `ConcurrentBag<T>`

Comment: `try {...} catch(Exception){throw;}` doesn't do anything. If you really want to ignore the error and its consequences, you should remove the `throw`. But don't ignore errors, especially this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't allow one thread to iterate over the list (Linq query) while another thread is adding to it. You can use a lock to achieve this. There's a performance penalty so you need to decide whether this solution works well enough for you depending on how fast you add new objects to the list and how long the list gets.

```
private object myLock = new Object();

void AddToList(SignalR s)
{
    lock(myLock) {
        SignalR.Add(s);
    }
}

void UpdateList() {
    lock(myLock)
    {
        var r = SignalR.Where(...).ToList();

        Filter3List.ItemsSource = r;
        Filter3List.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple threads accessing your list which will throw exceptions. Instead of `List<T>`, use `ConcurrentBag<T>`:

```
public static ConcurrentBag<SignalRounding> SignalR;
```

Note: This is in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace.

Comment: It breaks down all the techniques involved in List Type

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: There is still more errors during the replacement List<T> to ConcurrentBag<T>

Comment: Then you need to fix them! There is a very good reason that the concurrent list types exist.

Comment: Not sure that this is the only solution. It seems to me that there are more suitable.

Comment: Yes there is, write your own list that supports multithreading or wrap all of your access to the list in a `lock` statement. I know which option I would choose.

Comment: I thought that try-catch will eliminate the problem. That is, if the error appears, everything will continue to work. But for some reason this is not happening

Comment: I understand, but for some reason does not hide.

Comment: Not critical in my case)

Comment: Well you may think so, but it can hide other problems. Also throwing an exception is a very expensive process so it can make your application run slow. Fix the problem, don't hide it under the carpet.

Comment: If I do LINQ in a single thread and update the ListView in the other?

Comment: You are *still* going to have multiple threads accessing the same list. I can't give any more advice here, you are ignoring every suggestion.